# Whats NHibernate like for querying xml

Tags: xml, nhibernate, c#-4.0, css-selectors

I'm using nhibernate (n-hib-er-nate) to query the usual tables. Just wondering if it can query 
 xml.

Bob.

Comment: maybe is not the correct tool for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can return xml for quering in NHibernate 3.0 which provide support for xml columns.
Bob.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to query a XMLColumn using NHibernate, the [link](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/14/use-xml-field-in-sqlserver-with-nhibernate/) shows on how you can create a UserType to handle the XMLColumn.